# C# Создать форму только один раз

Tags: c#

При запуске программы появляется `Form1`, в которой находятся кнопки, которые ссылаются на другие формы (в частности `Form2`).

В этой `Form2` находится `dataGridView` и кнопка, которая ссылается на третью форму (`Form3`), которая служит для добавления данных в `dataGridView`.

Как можно объявить создание этой формы (`Form2`) только один раз, из главного меню (`Form1`) и при нажатии кнопки на `Form3`? И ссылаться на нее с других форм.

Очень надеюсь, что понятно объяснил.

Comment: Непонятно. Вы пишете «появляется Form1» — как? Происходит какая-то магия, или это _ваш код_ создаёт и показывает форму?

Comment: И что означает «кнопка ссылается на другую форму»?

Comment: Form3 - форма, в которой есть textBox'ы, из которых данные заносятся в dataGridView. Form2 - форма, в которой находится сам dataGridView и кнопка, которая создает и открывает Form3.

Comment: Form1 - главное окно программы, в нем несколько кнопок, одна из которых создает и открывает форму 2. Вот тут и хочу изменить, чтобы каждый раз новую форму не создавал, а скрывал, и показывал.

Comment: Ну, вы ж программист? Вы, наверное, понимаете, что окно создаёт не кнопка, а код, вызываемый по нажатию кнопки. Показывайте код.

Comment: `private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 form2 = new Form2();
            form2.Show();
        }` Это кнопка из главного меню (Form1). Можно ли сделать так, чтобы Form2 создавалась один раз на весь проект?

Comment: И при нажатии кнопки добавления данных в dataGridView, которая находится в Form3, тоже создается новая форма Form2.

Comment: `Form2.Hide(); Form2.Show();`  ?

Comment: @MichaelUkolov: Ну так создайте форму один раз и положите ссылку в общедоступное место.

Comment: А где ее создавать? В Form1? По идее, тогда снова нужно будет new Form1(); делать

Comment: @MichaelUkolov: Почему нужно будет? Кто вас заставит? Не надо вызывать снова `new Form1()`  — не вызывайте.

Answer (score 2):

Здесь может быть несколько вариантов решения.

ИМХО, самые оптимальные:

1. Создать закрытое поле в классе родительской формы и выполнять инициализацию в конструкторе

Например:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Form2 _form2;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _form2 = new Form2();
    }
}
```

2. Использовать паттерн Singleton

Этот вариант вообще избавляет от необходимости задумываться об инициализации нужной формы.
Код писать не стану, т.к.это один из основных паттернов и легко ищется в интернете. Включая [Википедию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)#C.23).